# Почему ломается верстка при переходе к блоку по ID в ссылке

Tags: css, html5, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

столкнулся с таким странным поведением: при переходе к блоку по ссылке /#next-btn, верстка почему-то улетает вверх. Почему так происходит и как переход по якорю (кажется, это так называется) влияет на стили страницы?

[image: Верстка до перехода по ID]

[image: Верстка после перехода]